# Format Range of Cells A Particular Currency Depending On Cell Value

Tags: vba, excel, currency-formatting

I've been trying to do IF statements and case statements to achieve this and nothing has been remotely successful.

Basically I have a 5 tab workbook that has different named ranges within each sheet that are meant to be a currency format.

However based on the value of a cell in the 1st tab (e.g. it could be CAD, USD, NOK, etc.) the currency format on those range of cells should change.

I.e. If the cell value in tab 1 is equal to CAD then all the named ranges in tabs 2-5 should be "$", if USD still "$", if NOK "kr " etc.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: can you show how your data looks like? sample data of course!!!

Comment: I'm attaching a link to my file here, let me know if there is another way to attach my file directly.
Basically, there is a dropdown menu in the 1st tab that will have the currency selection and then NAME1 and NAME2 named ranges should change to that currency. 

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B1mb0wVkbQcUdm42ZHVZNVFsVzQ/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

Record macro to get your currency format syntax and add to your IF statement ie..

```
Selection.NumberFormat = "[$kr-414] #,##0.00"
```

You also might consider using a `Case Select` instead of multiple `If`s

Comment: I didn't realize recording macro would actually work to show the currency formats...let me look into that, thank-you so much!

Answer (score 0):

You could put this code in the code of the Sheet of Tab1.
When the value of A1 Cell Changes, it triggers the tables of the sheets you need.

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)

Select Case Range("A1").Value
        Case "CAD"
        Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("Table1").NumberFormat = "#,##0.00 [$CAD]"
        Worksheets("Sheet3").Range("Table2").NumberFormat = "#,##0.00 [$CAD]"
        Worksheets("Sheet4").Range("Table3").NumberFormat = "#,##0.00 [$CAD]"
    Case "USD"
        Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("Table1").NumberFormat = "#,##0.00 [$USD]"
        Worksheets("Sheet3").Range("Table2").NumberFormat = "#,##0.00 [$USD]"
        Worksheets("Sheet4").Range("Table3").NumberFormat = "#,##0.00 [$USD]"
    Case "NOK"
        Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("Table1").NumberFormat = "#,##0.00 [$NOK]"
        Worksheets("Sheet3").Range("Table2").NumberFormat = "#,##0.00 [$NOK]"
        Worksheets("Sheet4").Range("Table3").NumberFormat = "#,##0.00 [$NOK]"
    End Select

End Sub
```